# How to stop Ember mouse event handlers from getting lagged

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

So I have a component that I am handling mouseEnter and mouseLeave events for, so that the component can slide down and up as the mouse enters and leave it.

I have done this in jQuery many times before without Ember and I don't remember this ever happening. Basically what happens is, it will execute every mouseEnter and mouseLeave event (stacking them on top of each other) so if a user accidentally mouses into the component and the mouse leaves and then goes back into it, it will slide down, then slide up, then slide down again. If I rapidly enter and exit it will slide down, up, down, up, down, up. as many times as I did it.

Couldn't find anything about this as it seems it's hard to find anything about obscure uses of Ember.

This is what I have in the component's JS file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['template-select', 'windows-select-container'],

  mouseEnter: function() {
    let $options = $('.windows-select-container > .vault-custom-container')
    $options.slideDown();
  },

  mouseLeave: function() {
    let $options = $('.windows-select-container > .vault-custom-container')
    $options.slideUp();
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it with closure actions? This could give you a performance boost. Also maybe debounce that a bit. Consider `ember-concurrency`.

Comment: Doing slideDown kind of animation stuff you can use [liquid-fire ember addon](https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire)

Comment: I haven't tried closure actions. I tried it with actions earlier without making it a component, but it didn't work but that stuff confuses me because it wants the actions in the controller for the route but then when I put it there it doesn't work, and can never figure out why.

Thinking about using a pure CSS solution if possible. See if I can transition the height from 0px to the height it is. The parent's container is set on height: auto which makes the container expand / shrink as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a Pure CSS approach, outlined below:

```
.windows-select-container {
    cursor: default !important;
}

.vault-custom-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: margin-top, height;
    -moz-transition-property: margin-top, height;
    transition-property: margin-top, height;
}

.windows-select-container:hover .vault-custom-container {
    margin-top: 25px !important;
    height: 44px !important;
}
```

Comment: I will probably change the `:hover` part to be the direct child instead of all elements (space) ... but otherwise this does what I need. Also somehow in addition to the 'lag' it also seemed to drop frames for some reason at points. Not sure why.